# How do I use I2C Sender app?

Tags: applications, usb-connection-mode

I read an article that described how to use the I2C Sender app, by Mirobicu, on an Android 'phone, but unfortunately I have lost the reference, please does anyone have the details of this app? I cannot locate any help files, and it is the I2C address of the app that I mostly need.

Answer (score 0):

By trial and error I have discovered that touching the screen at "12c Slave addr" or "Subaddr(HEX)" bring up lists of valid addresses to choose from.